Problem with texture paint and materials
I'm doing a school project in which we have to render a car. the problem is that they asked me for the livery and I have no idea how to maintain the carbon material and add the sponsors' logos. for the carbon I use a material found on blenderkit. the carbon appears procedurally generated. I tried to modify the carbon tree to include the livery tree, so 3 image pictures joined by 2 mix colors so as to have one image picture per layer. and then use an image pciture for Base and one for Decals and one for sponsors after which use an image to "draw" with the brush on the livery. I get 2 results 1 either the brush doesn't draw the image or 2 the image is drawn multiple times in random places.

If the image is being drawn "multiple times in random places" when texture painting, that would suggest to me that you have overlapping UV islands. Check your UV map.

Look up using Decals in Cycles, there are ways to overlay and place your decals in the same shader but with color mix nodes and multiple UV maps.
